# Communication between Java apps on 2 different servers(app1 in jboss and app2-tomcat) with https SSL configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jboss, ssl-certificate

Earlier when I kept both apps(app1 & app2) in the same (Jboss)server, I can call[communicate] the **api's** available in app1 from app2. [Jboss ssl configured with certificate]

Now My issue is, I moved only my app2 into tomcat server[app2],without changing any code and tried to connect **api's** of app1. It is throwing the **clientProtocol** Exception.

I came to know the issue with ssl certificate, because app1 is ssl configured.

Is there any place I have to configure my tomcat server to trust the app1 with the SSL jboss certifcate or in java program I have to add the trustmanager SSL socket code.

Please let me know the possible solution I have been stucked .

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the tomcat environment to know that exists a certificate to use.

This is done with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore` or setting it in `JAVA_OPTS`.

For Linux this is done as follow:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore
```

before calling `./startup.sh`